# Spring batch job to read multiple files and write to multiple tables

Tags: spring-batch

I need to create a spring batch job which takes multiple files and writes to multiple tables. Tried to use multiresourceitemwriter but my files are located in different folders and no common name. Looking for examples using ListItemReader and ListItemWriter. Any references are highly helpful.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the example at here

https://bigzidane.wordpress.com/2016/09/12/spring-batch-partitionerreaderprocesorwriterhibernateintellij/

I believe it fits to your question. If you need more question, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for pointers. but I have to pass the mutilple file names and multiple table names... like 1.dat,2,dat  table1,table2 and then 1.dat should be written to table1 and 2.dat to table2... my code is working for single file to single table..

Comment: Your input files are limited or unlimited, the same for your writers, in that limited or unlimited? Do you have pattern to know what input go with what writer.

Comment: Thank you @nghia do. I was able to find solution with the reference you mentioned.

Comment: Good to hear that.